# Calculate the sum of columns with PHP

Tags: php

I would like to calculate the sum of the numbers with highlight yellow color in a variable and the sum of the other values which are not highlighted in another variable.

My PHP code is:

```
$symbols=$request->Get('/_get?symbol=JAN&from=1586959285&to=1586959324&data=ba');
 if($symbols!=false) {
   echo $symbols;
 }
```

and the result of this code is:

```
{"retcode":"0 Done","answer":[[1.09076,1.09084],[1.09077,1.09086],[1.09072,1.09081],[1.09073,1.09082],[1.09073,1.09083],[1.09074,1.09084],[1.09082,1.09084],[1.09090,1.09097],[1.09091,1.09099],[1.09091,1.09100],[1.09093,1.09101],[1.09094,1.09102],[1.09095,1.09104],[1.09097,1.09106],[1.09098,1.09107],[1.09098,1.09108],[1.09099,1.09108],[1.09097,1.09106],[1.09096,1.09106],[1.09096,1.09105],[1.09097,1.09105],[1.09096,1.09105],[1.09095,1.09105],[1.09095,1.09104],[1.09093,1.09102],[1.09095,1.09102],[1.09095,1.09104],[1.09095,1.09103],[1.09093,1.09102],[1.09082,1.09090],[1.09082,1.09092],[1.09083,1.09092],[1.09082,1.09091],[1.09081,1.09090],[1.09080,1.09089],[1.09081,1.09090],[1.09080,1.09089],[1.09081,1.09089],[1.09080,1.09089],[1.09080,1.09088],[1.09078,1.09087],[1.09079,1.09088],[1.09079,1.09089],[1.09075,1.09084],[1.09074,1.09083],[1.09074,1.09084],[1.09074,1.09083],[1.09074,1.09084],[1.09074,1.09083],[1.09073,1.09083],[1.09074,1.09083],[1.09074,1.09084],[1.09074,1.09083],[1.09073,1.09083],[1.09073,1.09082],[1.09073,1.09083],[1.09074,1.09083],[1.09073,1.09082],[1.09073,1.09083],[1.09073,1.09082],[1.09072,1.09081],[1.09071,1.09081],[1.09072,1.09081],[1.09072,1.09083],[1.09073,1.09083]]}
```

If I  decode the JSON my code is:

```
$hugeArray = json_decode($symbols, true); 
foreach ($hugeArray as $key => $value) 
 {
   print_r($hugeArray);
 }
```

And the result is:

```
Array ( [retcode] => 0 Done [answer] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1.09076 [1] => 1.09084 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1.09077 [1] => 1.09086 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1.09072 [1] => 1.09081 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09082 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09083 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09084 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 1.09082 [1] => 1.09084 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 1.0909 [1] => 1.09097 ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 1.09091 [1] => 1.09099 ) [9] => Array ( [0] => 1.09091 [1] => 1.091 ) [10] => Array ( [0] => 1.09093 [1] => 1.09101 ) [11] => Array ( [0] => 1.09094 [1] => 1.09102 ) [12] => Array ( [0] => 1.09095 [1] => 1.09104 ) [13] => Array ( [0] => 1.09097 [1] => 1.09106 ) [14] => Array ( [0] => 1.09098 [1] => 1.09107 ) [15] => Array ( [0] => 1.09098 [1] => 1.09108 ) [16] => Array ( [0] => 1.09099 [1] => 1.09108 ) [17] => Array ( [0] => 1.09097 [1] => 1.09106 ) [18] => Array ( [0] => 1.09096 [1] => 1.09106 ) [19] => Array ( [0] => 1.09096 [1] => 1.09105 ) [20] => Array ( [0] => 1.09097 [1] => 1.09105 ) [21] => Array ( [0] => 1.09096 [1] => 1.09105 ) [22] => Array ( [0] => 1.09095 [1] => 1.09105 ) [23] => Array ( [0] => 1.09095 [1] => 1.09104 ) [24] => Array ( [0] => 1.09093 [1] => 1.09102 ) [25] => Array ( [0] => 1.09095 [1] => 1.09102 ) [26] => Array ( [0] => 1.09095 [1] => 1.09104 ) [27] => Array ( [0] => 1.09095 [1] => 1.09103 ) [28] => Array ( [0] => 1.09093 [1] => 1.09102 ) [29] => Array ( [0] => 1.09082 [1] => 1.0909 ) [30] => Array ( [0] => 1.09082 [1] => 1.09092 ) [31] => Array ( [0] => 1.09083 [1] => 1.09092 ) [32] => Array ( [0] => 1.09082 [1] => 1.09091 ) [33] => Array ( [0] => 1.09081 [1] => 1.0909 ) [34] => Array ( [0] => 1.0908 [1] => 1.09089 ) [35] => Array ( [0] => 1.09081 [1] => 1.0909 ) [36] => Array ( [0] => 1.0908 [1] => 1.09089 ) [37] => Array ( [0] => 1.09081 [1] => 1.09089 ) [38] => Array ( [0] => 1.0908 [1] => 1.09089 ) [39] => Array ( [0] => 1.0908 [1] => 1.09088 ) [40] => Array ( [0] => 1.09078 [1] => 1.09087 ) [41] => Array ( [0] => 1.09079 [1] => 1.09088 ) [42] => Array ( [0] => 1.09079 [1] => 1.09089 ) [43] => Array ( [0] => 1.09075 [1] => 1.09084 ) [44] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09083 ) [45] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09084 ) [46] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09083 ) [47] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09084 ) [48] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09083 ) [49] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09083 ) [50] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09083 ) [51] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09084 ) [52] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09083 ) [53] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09083 ) [54] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09082 ) [55] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09083 ) [56] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09083 ) [57] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09082 ) [58] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09083 ) [59] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09082 ) [60] => Array ( [0] => 1.09072 [1] => 1.09081 ) [61] => Array ( [0] => 1.09071 [1] => 1.09081 ) [62] => Array ( [0] => 1.09072 [1] => 1.09081 ) [63] => Array ( [0] => 1.09072 [1] => 1.09083 ) [64] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09083 ) ) ) Array ( [retcode] => 0 Done [answer] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1.09076 [1] => 1.09084 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1.09077 [1] => 1.09086 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1.09072 [1] => 1.09081 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09082 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09083 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09084 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 1.09082 [1] => 1.09084 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 1.0909 [1] => 1.09097 ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 1.09091 [1] => 1.09099 ) [9] => Array ( [0] => 1.09091 [1] => 1.091 ) [10] => Array ( [0] => 1.09093 [1] => 1.09101 ) [11] => Array ( [0] => 1.09094 [1] => 1.09102 ) [12] => Array ( [0] => 1.09095 [1] => 1.09104 ) [13] => Array ( [0] => 1.09097 [1] => 1.09106 ) [14] => Array ( [0] => 1.09098 [1] => 1.09107 ) [15] => Array ( [0] => 1.09098 [1] => 1.09108 ) [16] => Array ( [0] => 1.09099 [1] => 1.09108 ) [17] => Array ( [0] => 1.09097 [1] => 1.09106 ) [18] => Array ( [0] => 1.09096 [1] => 1.09106 ) [19] => Array ( [0] => 1.09096 [1] => 1.09105 ) [20] => Array ( [0] => 1.09097 [1] => 1.09105 ) [21] => Array ( [0] => 1.09096 [1] => 1.09105 ) [22] => Array ( [0] => 1.09095 [1] => 1.09105 ) [23] => Array ( [0] => 1.09095 [1] => 1.09104 ) [24] => Array ( [0] => 1.09093 [1] => 1.09102 ) [25] => Array ( [0] => 1.09095 [1] => 1.09102 ) [26] => Array ( [0] => 1.09095 [1] => 1.09104 ) [27] => Array ( [0] => 1.09095 [1] => 1.09103 ) [28] => Array ( [0] => 1.09093 [1] => 1.09102 ) [29] => Array ( [0] => 1.09082 [1] => 1.0909 ) [30] => Array ( [0] => 1.09082 [1] => 1.09092 ) [31] => Array ( [0] => 1.09083 [1] => 1.09092 ) [32] => Array ( [0] => 1.09082 [1] => 1.09091 ) [33] => Array ( [0] => 1.09081 [1] => 1.0909 ) [34] => Array ( [0] => 1.0908 [1] => 1.09089 ) [35] => Array ( [0] => 1.09081 [1] => 1.0909 ) [36] => Array ( [0] => 1.0908 [1] => 1.09089 ) [37] => Array ( [0] => 1.09081 [1] => 1.09089 ) [38] => Array ( [0] => 1.0908 [1] => 1.09089 ) [39] => Array ( [0] => 1.0908 [1] => 1.09088 ) [40] => Array ( [0] => 1.09078 [1] => 1.09087 ) [41] => Array ( [0] => 1.09079 [1] => 1.09088 ) [42] => Array ( [0] => 1.09079 [1] => 1.09089 ) [43] => Array ( [0] => 1.09075 [1] => 1.09084 ) [44] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09083 ) [45] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09084 ) [46] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09083 ) [47] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09084 ) [48] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09083 ) [49] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09083 ) [50] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09083 ) [51] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09084 ) [52] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09083 ) [53] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09083 ) [54] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09082 ) [55] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09083 ) [56] => Array ( [0] => 1.09074 [1] => 1.09083 ) [57] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09082 ) [58] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09083 ) [59] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09082 ) [60] => Array ( [0] => 1.09072 [1] => 1.09081 ) [61] => Array ( [0] => 1.09071 [1] => 1.09081 ) [62] => Array ( [0] => 1.09072 [1] => 1.09081 ) [63] => Array ( [0] => 1.09072 [1] => 1.09083 ) [64] => Array ( [0] => 1.09073 [1] => 1.09083 ) ) )
```

Any Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First suggestion would be to decode the JSON and see if you can loop through the values..should be easy to sum it then

Comment: Can you share the "input" as code not as a picture?